# Database project warnings

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, warnings, database-project

I've imported an existing database into a database project in Visual Studio. I'm getting a few types of warnings which I want to make go away:

- The database objects have quite a few references to the name of other databases. For example,

  `SELECT * FROM [databaseA]..Test t1 INNER JOIN [databaseB]..Test t2 on t1.id = t2.id`

  Is there a simple way to either resolve these warnings or, if necessary, just suppress these warnings? I don't want to have to make separate projects for the other databases, as they are for self-contained 3rd party applications whose schema we don't touch.
- We are getting some warnings for using OPENROWSET in a few procedures. I understand that VS cannot safely verify these operations at build time, but I want to suppress these warnings.

For reference, we're using VS 2012 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a dacpac file for the other databases using SQLPackage.exe (assuming you're using SQLProj files). If you're using DBProj files, you'll want to use VSDBCMD.exe to create DBSchema files. Put those someplace your projects can reference them and add them as database references. You don't need to create separate projects for them, but do need some way to indicate that those databases are valid.

To suppress warnings, you can take the warning number and either tweak the properties of the file(s) to suppress the warning or you can go to your project properties to suppress warnings for all files. The list can be entered in a CSV format so multiple warnings can be suppressed.